# Powershell replace part of content of one file by content of another file

Tags: powershell

I have text1.txt file with following content:

```
sometext_1
--start
sometext_2.1
sometext_2.2
...
sometext_2.n
--end
sometext_3
```

and text2.txt file with following content:

```
--start
sometext_2_new1
sometext_2_new2
...
sometext_2_newn
--end
```

Could someone help me to write Powershell code to update content of text1.txt file between keywords **--start** and **--end** with all content of file text2.txt?
So the new text1.txt will look like below:

```
sometext_1
--start
sometext_2_new1
sometext_2_new2
...
sometext_2_newn
--end
sometext_3
```

**UPDATE:**
I'm really new in Powershell. After some research I was able to came up with following which is still not giving me what I need:

```
param(
[string]$location
)

$contentStart = Get-Content "c:\text2.txt"

$configFiles = Get-ChildItem $location\*.txt -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "--start.*?(--end)", $contentStart } |
    Out-File $file.PSPath
}
```

But it works only if text1.txt has keywords **--start** and **--end** in one line and relult is following (inserted content do not have endline symbols):

```
sometext_1
--start sometext_2_new1 sometext_2_new2 ... sometext_2_newn --end
sometext_3
```

Comment: Do you have anything to start from? "Please write code for me" posts are generally discouraged. The proper code will be more useful if you understand it as well.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit involved because you need to create a regular expression with SingleLine mode.

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    Get-Content $file.PSPath -Raw |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "(?s)(--start`r`n).*?(`r`n--end)", "`$1$contentStart`$2" } |
    Out-File $file.PSPath
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `-Raw` switch for `Get-Content` tells the cmdlet to get everything as one single string, rather than an array of lines like it normally does.

There's only one item going through the pipeline now for each file, but we still need the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet to enumerate the item for us.

Now, to explain the regex:

```
"(?s)(--start`r`n).*?(`r`n--end)"
```

The `(?s)` is the [regular expression option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) for single line mode.  This means that the `.` character will match line endings.  Normally it doesn't.

Next, there's the rest of the regex, `` (--start`r`n).*?(`r`n--end) ``.  The `--start` and `--end` are pretty obvious.  The Windows line ending characters are `` `r `` is expressed as `\r` for carriage return in most other languages and `` `n `` is `\n` for end of line in most other languages.  They need to be included in order for the `.*?` not to eat them in single line mode.  The parentheses are for grouping for backreferences.  The first parenthetic group will become `$1`, and the second will become `$2`, etc.

Note that if your text file is not using Windows line endings you may need to modify this regex appropriately.

The replace string:

```
"`$1$contentStart`$2"
```

Here, we're using double quotes so that the PowerShell variable, `$contentStart` can be inlined into the string.  And `$1` and `$2` are present as the backreference variables to the groups in the regular expression.  However, we run into a problem with the backreference variables.  They're `$1` and `$2`, which are valid variables in PowerShell.  So, we need to escape the dollar sign with another backtick.

Comment: It gives me empty output file.

Answer (score 2):

I like Regex101.com to test and refine the Regular Expression I develop.
See [here your example](https://regex101.com/r/MizgEV/2)

You need to tell the RegEx with:

- `m` flag that `^` and `$` match line begin/end
- `s` flag that the `.` dot also matches new line

---

```
PS> $text1 = Get-Content ".\text1.txt"
PS> $text2 = Get-Content ".\text2.txt"
PS> $text1 -replace "(?ms)^--start$.*?^--end$",$text2
sometext_1
--start
sometext_2.1
sometext_2.2
...
sometext_2.n
--end
sometext_3
```

Comment: I do like your regex better than mine.  I'd forgotten about the multiline option.  I'm not sure if it will delete the `--start` and `--end` lines though?